# Amazon SNS sending confirmation that SMS text message was sent with Ruby SDK

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, sms

I'm sending SMS text messages using Amazon SNS with Ruby Amazon SDK. As far I understood, the method `Aws::SNS::Client#publish` just enqueues the message sending.

> When a messageId is returned, the message has been saved and Amazon SNS will attempt to deliver it to the topic's subscribers shortly.

I'd to know if the `publish` method just enqueues the sending and if so, is there any way to confirm with the SDK that the message was successfully sent?

Comment: Assume you meant to say "SNS" in the title?

Comment: Not necessarily. I thought that "SMS" (short message service) term would be more explicitly about which part of Amazon SNS I'm having trouble but don't worry, Amazon SNS is correct too.

Comment: That makes sense--I edited to include both--hope that's OK with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query for topics or for subscriptions, but you can't query for published messages. I doubt AWS keeps them, but if they do, there is no API to access them so far as I know.

One workaround would be to subscribe to each of your own topics using an http or https endpoint on your own site. Each time you create a topic, you would create a corresponding subscription to your own endpoint:

```
def generate_sns_topic(topic_name)
  sns_client = Aws::SNS::Client.new
  response = sns_client.create_topic(name: topic_name)
  if response.successful?
     sns_client.subscribe(topic_arn: topic_response.topic_arn, 
                          protocol: :https, 
                          endpoint: <your_site_endpoint>)
  else
    <error_handling_here>
  end
end
```

Now you need to create `POST <your_site_endpoint>` to accept the AWS message as it comes in. Once you receive it, you'll know SNS has sent it. Presumably you'll create a new `published_messages` table in your database to keep track of what's been published.

Comment: Got it, I'll try your suggestion! Thank you!